# Applying ID to button for dynamic linking

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting a strange recursion error when applying the id with php but it only seems to be happening when it's a string "MAI001". Works perfectly when it's just an int "123", I'm not too sure on what to do?

```
$(<?php echo "'#". $row->id."'";?>).on('click', function(){

                         $.ajax({
                           url: 'load_contractor', // link to CI function
                           type: 'POST',
                           data: {  
                             contractor_id: <?php echo $row->id;?> ,
                           },
                           success: function (data) {
                               window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('Panel/Admin/index'); ?>";

                           }
                         });

                       });
```

Comment: I'm also new to what you're doing so it'll be great if you can bring us up to speed about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Might be your API accepts only int values. What is error?

Comment: What is the "strange recursion error"?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically add the ID so when the button is clicked, the user will be taken to the page loaded with the info for that specific ID :)

Comment: It just says recursion error in the console, but then when a plain int is applied to the ID it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have quotes in your js object. So it wants `$row->id` to be integer. And when you pass string to it, it fails.

Right code here:

```
$(<?= "'#$row->id'";?>).on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'load_contractor', // link to CI function
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            contractor_id: <?= "'$row->id'";?> ,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "<?= site_url('Panel/Admin/index'); ?>";

        }
    });
});
```

P.S. I replaced all your `<?php echo` with short syntax `<?=` for better readability. It is normal in PHP world to use this syntax. If you use old PHP (below 5.4.0) and didn't enable short syntax, you should replace it back.